# Is there a way to get an optional bind mount in docker swarm

Tags: docker-swarm

I have a swarm service that bind-mounts a file that may not exist. If the file does not exist the service fails to deploy (and I get logs complaining about the missing file). I would prefer to have the service deploy anyway, just missing that mount. Is there a way to let that happen?

The being being mounted is a unix socket to a local memcached instance. The app can run without it and we don't run memcached on every node, so I'd like to allow the service to deploy even if the bind mount fails (if the ideal node goes down and the service has to move to another node that doesn't run memcached).

I realize I could move the mount point to a directory that will always exist on every host machine, but I'd prefer to keep the bind mount exposure minimal if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a similar scenario and I implemented a NFS server in one node and then I mount it in every swarm node. So, I always have files in the same path.